# Which one is a better practice? Declare a variable inside or outside of a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Which one is better in terms of best practice and memory-saving when there are many items in the list?

Please note that this is just a mock-up example which is modified and simplified from actual company codebase.

The first scenario will only create the variable "result" once and then reuse it inside the loop.

```
ls = ['apple', 'banana', 'cucumber']
result = ""

for i in ls:
    result = i + i
    print(result)
```

The second scenario, the code creates the variable "result" in each loops.

```
ls = ['apple', 'banana', 'cucumber']

for i in ls:
    result = i + i
    print(result)
```

Comment: The `result` variable isn't necessary in either example.

Comment: I am just making up the examples. Can't post the entire company codes here. I just want to know in the case you are required to create the "result" variable.

Comment: Python doesn't have variable declarations. Providing a definition whose value you never use serves no purpose. (Specifically, there is no reason to define `result = ""` if that value will never be used and just redefined to something else in the loop.)

Comment: In this case, `result = ""` is unnecessary since `result = i + i` is always done before `result` is used, and `result` is never needed outside of the loop (which would cause problems if `ls` were empty).

Comment: Exception: if it's possible that the loop body is never entered (`ls` is an empty iterable, for example), then you *might* want to assign some default value before the loop to ensure the variable is defined regardless of the value of `ls`.

Comment: I should specify in my original post. The actual code is way bigger and makes api calls. My focus is to know if it makes any difference to declare the variable inside or outside of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use `result` inside the loop, there's no reason at all to define it outside the loop. Python doesn't require variables to be declared at the top of a function or anything. If that's a thing you've learned from other programming languages, know that it that doesn't need to exist in your Python code. There's no performance penalty for assigning to a variable for the first time versus using it after it already exists. If anything, the initial assignment might be faster than subsequent re-use, since reuse might require garbage collecting the old value.

That said, if you do use the variable after the loop ends, than there *might* be a reason to set a value in advance: The loop might never run if the object you iterate over is empty. For example:

```
ls = []
result = None                   # set an initial value before the loop

for i in ls:
    result = i + i              # this assignment never runs, since ls is empty
    print(result)

print("Final result:", result)  # therefore, this will use the initial value
```

Giving some thought to what your code will do if a sequence you're looping over is empty is a good idea in general. Some times you will know in advance that it will not occur, but in cases where you do not know that, it's wise to be prepared.